# How do you maintain on Python the value of the last row in a column, like on excel?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, database, dataframe, excel-formula

I have looked around and haven't found an 'elegant' solution. It can't be that it is not doable.
What I need is to have a column ('col A') on a dataframe that it is always 0, if the adjacent ('col B') column hits 1, then change the value to 1, and all further rows should be 1 (no matter what else happens on 'col B'), until another column ('col C') hits 1, then 'col A' returns to 0, until this repeats. The data has thousands of rows, and it gets updated regularly.
any ideas? I have tried shift, iloc and loops, but can't make it work.
the result should look something like this:

[sample data][1]

```
date col A col B col C
...   0     0     0
...   0     0     0
...   1     1     0
...   1     1     0
...   1     0     1
...   0     0     0
...   0     0     0
...   1     1     0
...   1     1     0
...   1     0     0
...   1     0     0
...   1     1     0
...   1     0     0
...   1     1     0
...   1     0     1
...   0     0     0
```

This is the base code I have been thinking about, but I can't get it to work:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 1 else 0)

for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if df.loc[i, 'C'] == 1:
        df.loc[i, 'B'] = 0
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'B'] = df.loc[i-1, 'B']
```

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am very new here, so thank you so much for answering! I have something like this, and then just look over the shifted column, but it doesn´t work well and you need to loop through it many times. I need to do calculate a bunch of metrics and if the tests fails the dataframe should keep the previous value. df['col C'] = df['col B'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 1 else 0)
df['col D'] = df['col C'].shift(1)

Comment: to clarify, according to the question, are column B elements = 1 for all elements below row 3 ?

Comment: yes, until column C prints a 1. in other words, when the first 1 appears on column A, all future values of column B should be maintained, until column C prints a 1.

Comment: ...and what is the rule of columns A and C give conflicting signals ? ut appears as though hte question needs to be modified, with an example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: column A becomes a 1 when certain value in the df exceeds a variable. the same is true to for column C. column A is not dependent on any other related column, however column C, is dependent on column B becoming a 1 at some point.